# Verilog: Concatenate bus and indexing

Tags: concatenation, verilog, bus

I can create a bus as below:

```
reg [2:0] a;
wire x,y,z;
assign {x,y,z} = a;
```

Can I use {x,y,z}[1:0] ?

Comment: You must select the bus individually. Like `reg [5:0] a; wire [1:0] x,y,z; assign {x[1:0],y[1:0],z[1:0]} = a;`.

Comment: Verilog allows muxes to declared as below:
input [0:1] sel;
output y;
wire [15:0] choice;
y=choice[sel];

So isnt there a way to index a concatenated bus?

Comment: You can use as you mentioned in comment, Can you please elaborate your whole requirement? with pseudo example?

Comment: If there is a n input mux for (2^n) inputs, that selects 1 output, the model for the mux is defined as
module (input [n-1]:0 sel, input x0, input x1, ...input xn-1, output y);
endmodule
I want to just 'model' it as 
assign y = {x0,x1,...xn-1}[sel];

This does not get read by some tools!

Comment: Like? Can you give one example? suppose N=4, then as per your description 4 Muxes are there having 2^N = 16 Inputs, so how select line is of 4 bit wide? if you want to select any one mux output you require log2N = 2-bits only.

Comment: If I have to select 1 out of 2^4 bits, I would need 4 bits for selection.  How can I select using 2 bits?m

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is allowed in SystemVerilog.